# closing simple content tag on a XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I am having problems validating a XML file again XML schema. Any help?

Link: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=f640c556-1da8-4cc4-a50c-b72f9d7a8780-xsdvalidation

XSD FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsd:schema
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="asdasdasdasd">
    <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">


<xsd:element name="student">
    <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="firstname">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="lastname">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:element>      
            <xsd:element name="email">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:element>      
        <xsd:element name="dateofbirth">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:date"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:element>      
        <xsd:element name="major">
            <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Computer Science/SD" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Computer Science/IT" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Math" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:attribute name="stuid" type="xsd:integer"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:element>



    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:element>



</xsd:schema>
```

XML FILE:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <asdasd>


    <student xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://unixweb.kutztown.edu/~agyaw792/480/hw2xsd.xsd" stuid="002">

             <firstname>John</firstname>
             <lastname>Doe</lastname>
             <email>jdoe619@live.kutztown.edu</email>
             <dateofbirth>2002-09-24</dateofbirth>
             <major>Computer Science/SD</major>

             </student>

             <student stuid="007">
             <firstname>Mary</firstname>
             <lastname>Smith</lastname>
             <email>msmit789@live.kutztown.edu</email>
             <dateofbirth>2004-02-32</dateofbirth>
             <major>Computer Science/IT</major>
             </student>

              <student stuid="123">
             <firstname>Harry</firstname>
             <lastname>Potter</lastname>
             <email>hpott455@live.kutztown.edu</email>
             <dateofbirth>2004-02-12</dateofbirth>
             <major>Math</major>
             </student>

             </asdasdasdasd>
```

I am pretty new to this stuff so I might be doing something silly here. Apologies in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a decent xml editor or an IDE with xml help, you would've spotted an error here:

```
<xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" />   // closed
</xsd:restriction>                    // closing tag with no starting tag
</xsd:simpleContent>
```

You're closing off the start tag for the restriction unnecessarily. Either remove the closing tag or remove the slash in the starting tag. The same goes for *all* your elements with restrictions. You're doing the exact same thing on all of them

But in another light, why have the restriction at all. Just put the type of for `firstName` to `xsd:string`. Why the need for a restriction in this case? Same goes for the rest of your elements using the same pattern.

Also, not great practice to have a bunch of anonymous type. Consider declaring outside

Other problems spotted:

You're student id attribute is an attrubute of student elements, so should go outside choice

```
       <xsd:attribute name="stuid" type="xsd:integer"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:choice>
```

You don't need `simpleContent` inside of `simpleType`. Take the out.

```
<xsd:element name="major">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
```

Here's a complete refactor of your xsd to make it valid

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Author: Ankit Gyawalient
            Creation Date: September
            8th, 2014
            Due Date: September 10th, 2014
            Course: CSC 480 010
            Professor
            Name: Dr. Lisa Frye
            Assignment: 2
            Filename: hw2xsd.xsd
            Purpose: To
            define XML Schema for a university in an external file and use it
            appropriately.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>

    <xsd:element name="asdasdasdasd">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="student">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xsd:element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="email" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="dateofbirth" type="xsd:date" />
                            <xsd:element name="major">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:enumeration value="Computer Science/SD" />
                                        <xsd:enumeration value="Computer Science/IT" />
                                        <xsd:enumeration value="Math" />
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:choice>
                        <xsd:attribute name="stuid" type="xsd:integer" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

---

And finally in your xml file you have this

```
<dateofbirth>2004-02-32</dateofbirth>
```

Sorry no such date as February 32nd. At least that xml is concerned :-)

The above changes will pass. As a side note, have a look at [this tutorial](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/index.html) for a good reference guide